# adding a custom icon to a panel in kde-plasma

Tags: kde, manjaro, plasma

I am building a kde environment in manjaro very much like gnome-2. so far I've been able to build panels with application icons from the application launcher. However, I have built some applications from sources that either are not in the repositories, or don't work from there, and I would like to put a launcher on a panel that I can customize. In gnome-flashback, this is completely straight forward. How do I ask for essentially a blank application launcher in a panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Menu Editor (you can find it in Plasma search) to create a custom application entry. This will then show up like your repo-installed applications and can e.g. be dragged from the application menu into the panel to create a launcher.